# How to get difference of two images using cv2 in a format so that it can be reapplied later?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am looking to get the difference between img1 and img2 using cv2 in python, in a way that I can reapply the difference to img1.

Essentially: Difference = img2 - img1

In a format where I can later declare:
img2 = img1 + difference

I am well aware of the cv2 functions absdiff, subtract and add. However I have not managed to extract the diff in a format that would allow addition later on.

Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. In case anybody is wondering why? The difference would be sent over socket and reapplied to img1 which was sent or constructed prior.

Comment: `cv2` uses `numpy array` so as for me it should work `difference = img2 - img1` and later `img2 = img1 + difference` because it is only array with numbers. Only problem it to send it by socket. It may need to convert `numpy array` to string, send this string, and convert string back to `numpy array`

Comment: original image use dtype `uint8` (0...255) but `diff` may gives values smaller then 0 ( 0  -255) and it may need first convert to `int16` to have values `-255 ... +255`

Comment: I have the sending figured out, and I came to same approach as above regarding the numpy subtraction and addition. However the image is super grainy, any ideas as to why?

Comment: **abs**diff gives you the **absolute** difference, but you need the sign, so do a regular difference. **no need** for `int16`. uint8 is perfectly capable of wrapping around. -- let me guess, you're working with **JPEG** files. that's **lossy** compression.

Answer (score 3):

Original image uses dtype `uint8` with values `0..255` but when you substract then you can get values `-255..255` `(0-255)..(255-0)` and it needs to convert to `int16`

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
print('img1:', img1.shape, img1.dtype)

img2 = cv2.imread('lenna_flip.png')
print('img2:', img2.shape, img2.dtype)

diff = img2.astype('int16') - img1.astype('int16')
print('diff:', diff.shape, diff.dtype)

cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)

back = (img1.astype('int16') + diff).astype('uint8')
print('back:', back.shape, back.dtype)

cv2.imshow('back', back)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`back` gives correct image but `diff` gives gray image (because it has values -255...255 which it converts to `0..255` when it displays)  so it is useless to display it.

But now you have to send array `diff` with `int16` so it may need to send more bytes then using original image and maybe it would be faster to send original image.

---

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

lenna.png

[image]

lenna_flip.png

[image]